# How to mock static method calls from multiple classes in a single try block using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to mock static methods from two different classes. Right now, my code is like this:

```
try(MockedStatic<ObjectFactory> objectFactory = mockStatic(ObjectFactory.class)){
    objectFactory.when(() -> ObjectFactory.getObject(Provider.class)).thenReturn(new Provider());
    .....
}
```

I want to mock another static method call from `Context.class`. Is there a way to define a `MockedStatic` object of context in the same try block, without using a nested try block.

Without using try block I think we can use something like this

```
MockedStatic<ObjectFactory> objectFactory = mockStatic(ObjectFactory.class);
MockedStatic<Context> contextMock = mockStatic(Context.class);
......
objectFactory.close();
contextMock.close();
```

but if the test throws exception, the mocks will not be closed and other tests that use the mock will throw an exception.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `try-with-resources` statement can define multiple `AutoCloseable` instances, both of which will be closed at the end:

```
try (MockedStatic<ObjectFactory> objectFactory = mockStatic(ObjectFactory.class);
     MockedStatic<Context> contextMock = mockStatic(Context.class)) {
```